# Cartesian product length with dictionary and constraint function

Tags: python-3.x, performance, dictionary, python-itertools

I have a dictionary that looks like this:

```
parameters = dict(
    key_1     = range(40,220),
    key_2     = range(40,220),
    key_3     = range(5,25),
    key_4     = range(-580,-80),
    constraint      = lambda param: param.key_1 >= (param.key_2 +1 6) and
                                    (param.key_1 % 4 == 0) and
                                    (param.key_2 % 4 == 0) and 
                                    (param.key_4 % 4 == 0),
)
```

I would like to know the length of the resulting cartesian product after applying the constraint function.

I can do it without the constraint function with itertools:

```
import itertools
def _calculate_num_configurations( **kwargs) -> int:
    constraint = kwargs['constraint']
    parameters = kwargs
    del parameters['constraint']
    
    ranges = []
    for parameter_range in parameters.values():
        ranges.append(parameter_range)

    return len(list(itertools.product(*ranges)))
```

But I am not able to do it applying the function. I know filterfalse from itertools can be used, but I am not able to make it work together with my dictionary keys.

The solutions I have implemented until now take a very long time of processing when the total combinations are around hundred millions.

Do you have any idea how to calculate the length in an efficient way?